# Deriving fields data from grouped data in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to PIG. Below is the code:

```
a = load 'stage.temp' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = limit a 10;
c = group b by $0;
dump c;

(74409607,{(74409607,a,2),(74409607,b,1)})
(74409607,{(74409607,c,4),(74409607,d,5)})
(74409735,{(74409735,NA,159),(74409735,,158)})
```

How could we generate this from above operator c?

```
(74409607,{(2,a),(1,b),(4,c),(5,d)})
(74409735,{(159,NA),(158,)})
```

Comment: Post sample data

Answer (score 0):

Swap the second and third columns while enumerating each group.

```
d = foreach c generate group,a.$2,a.$1;
```

Note: When you group by $0 and dump c you should be getting

```
(74409607,{(74409607,a,2),(74409607,b,1),(74409607,c,4),(74409607,d,5)})
(74409735,{(74409735,NA,159),(74409735,,158)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the output you posted is what you obtained from that dump statement ?

From what I see this should be the output.

(**74409607**,{*(74409607,d,5),(74409607,c,4),(74409607,b,1),(74409607,a,2)*})
(**74409735**,{*(74409735,,158),(74409735,NA,159)*})

Coming to your question, group by operator in pig will give you the output as a bag having the grouped column (in Bold) and all the rows(italicized) that are having the same value .

You can how ever fetch the required fields from the bag using the relation c .